# Omitting return in async typed function

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, async-await, return

Let's see an example:

```
export async function foo(): Promise<string>{
  await bar()
  return;
}
```

It compiles without an error.

Then,

```
export async function foo(): Promise<string>{
  await bar()
}
```

results in error

> A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value

1) Why?

I guess it is something with https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#63-function-implementations

and complicated by using async, typescript and its typing?

UPDATE:

FYI, when function has `return;` has not `return` (or even has `return undefined;`), it is the same situation from the semantics perspective, right?

Comment: If you define a return type then you need a return statement. _" it is the same situation from the semantics perspective"_ No. It has the effect in JavaScript but it's semantically different in TypeScript. Otherwise you wouldn't get that error.

Comment: Can you send me a link to a documentation saying this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of explicitly providing a return type other than `Void` or `Any` is that you want to ensure type safety. And you implicitly tell the compiler that you actually want to return something. That's why the compiler expects you to do this and complains when you don't. It's defined in the TypeScript specification [section 6.1](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#6.1):

> An explicitly typed function whose return type isn't the Void type, the Any type, or a union type containing the Void or Any type as a constituent must have at least one return statement somewhere in its body

As for your question concerning `return`, you are right.

`return;` and `return undefined;` have the same outcome, that's defined by the ECMAScript specification [section 13.10](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-return-statement):

> If Expression is omitted, the return value is undefined.

Omitting the `return` statement also has the same effect, as defined in [section 9.2.1](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist). Step 11 basically says that `undefined` is returned if nothing else has been returned (Step 9) or no exception has been thrown (Step 10).

So while your examples lead to the same result (returning `undefined`) in JavaScript, they are semantically different for the TypeScript compiler (the second ex. doesn't return anything).

Answer (score 4):

This is not really related to `async/await` the empty return is treated as `return undefined`. So this also works:

```
function foo(): string{
    return; // equivalent to return undefined;
}
```

If you use `strictNullChecks` you will get an error as `undefined` is not assignable to `string`

If you omit the return completely the compiler would infer the return type as `void` which is different from the declared type of `string` and thus this would be an error. Same applies if the function is `async` and returns a `Promise`

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to have strict type checking you should set

```
    "strictNullChecks": true
```

in you `tsconfig.json` file.

when you have a function like this

```
async function (): Promise<string> {
   return; // same as return undefined
}
```

if your `tsconfig.json` doesn't have `strictNullChecks" set to true, then compiling will pass through without an error.

Check [docs/handbook/compiler-options.html](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Promise<void>` if you don't plan on returning the Promise.

Comment: That's not true. See my first example. I didn't have to use it and it works. I updated my question,

Comment: Yes, but there you return an undefined which is valid. You could also return null there.

Comment: But `return;`  `return undefined;`  and `// return;`, they are all equivalent, right?

Comment: @WojtylaCz The first two are equivalent. The latter is not. If you omit the return then well you return nothing.

Comment: Cannot be. There is nothing like return nothing. There is always an implicit return.

Comment: You are returning an `undefined` which is a primitive datatype. There is no implicit return for undefined.

Comment: Can you send me a link into a documentation to proof that, please?

Comment: Are you really questioning a high rep user? Why would you ask a question if you can't accept the answer...

Comment: Do you believe that a user with high rep. is always correct and he does not make a mistakes? Trust, but verify. Give me a documentation and I'm quiet.

Comment: `undefined` is the implicit return value of a function without a `return` expression: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-return-statement

Answer (score 1):

By using the return type annotation (`: Promise<string>`) you are saying that the function will return something (a Promise that may resolve to a string at some future point), so a function without a `return` statement clearly goes against that annotation/intent.

To mark the function as not returning anything, you may use the annotation `: void` instead, but this may cause a different error about not being able to coerce undefined to a Promise), so in this case `: Promise<void>` may be more appropriate.

It doesn't matter in your example that you have an empty `return` expression, because with an `async` function, if you return a non-promise value, it will automatically be wrapped in a promise, so the `return;` will still be correct from the compiler's perspective.